# JQuery animation lag

Tags: jquery, animation, lag

I'm working on a gallery for the picbox.us site and I'm getting lag when I hover over an image. It's supposed to just animate the height of my image info to 40 and that's it. But sometimes it lags, or delays. Here is the page: http://zachrip.net/widgets/gallery/

Here is the only code pertaining to the issue:

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".image").hover(
function () {
$("#" + this.id + "info").animate({height: '40'}, 700);
}
);
$(body).hover(
function(){
    $(".imageinfo").animate({height: '0'}, 700);
}
);
$("#container").hover(
function(){
    $(".imageinfo").animate({height: '0'}, 700);
}
);
});
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div id='container'>
<center>
<p>Beta testing image gallery</p>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td><center><img class="image" id="1" src="img1.png"/></center><p id="1info" class="imageinfo">Uploaded by muny</p></td>
<td><center><img class="image" id="2" src="img1.png"/></center><p id="2info" class="imageinfo">Uploaded by zachrip</p></td>
<td><center><img class="image" id="3" src="img1.png"/></center><p id="3info"  class="imageinfo">Uploaded by seanrice</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: Upload your code for review

Comment: Why this: `$(body).hover(
function(){
    $(".imageinfo").animate({height: '0'}, 700);
}`?  That does not look like a good idea and could be causing the problem.

Comment: That just closes the image info when you leave the image.

Comment: You should really review your CSS and all other scripts in at least 2 or 3 browsers. (Firefox in your case :) )

Comment: Just working on chrome at the moment. In the end I make everything compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

http://jsbin.com/uzucuh/1/edit

```
$('.imgBox').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( ev ){  
  var mEnt = ev.type=='mouseenter'; 
  $('span', this).stop().animate({bottom: mEnt? 40 : 0 }, 300);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image").mouseenter(
    function() {
        $("#"+this.id+"info").animate({
            height: '40'
        }, 500);
    });
    $(".image").mouseleave(
    function() {
        $("#"+this.id+"info").animate({
            height: '0'
        }, 500);
    });
});​
```

Another way to write the above is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image").hover(
    function() {
      $("#"+this.id+"info").animate({
        height: '40'
      }, 500);
    },
    function() {
      $("#"+this.id+"info").animate({
        height: '0'
      }, 500);
    });
});​
```

Basically I replaced your hover events with mouse enter and exit events. I also reduced the amount of time to complete the animations from 700 milliseconds to 500.

On a side note, your source code needs a bit of modification. You're importing `jquery-ui.min.js` in your header, and `query.js` half way down the page. You should import `query.js` in the footer, and `ui.min.js` after `query.js`. Also the paths to `includes/jquery.inview.js` and `includes/muny.js` are wrong.